# Given two set of eigenvectors, can one be represented by another?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E_1$ be a set of eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ and $E_2$ be a set of eigenvectors with
eigenvalue $\lambda_2$, $\lambda_2 \neq \lambda_1$.

Prove or disprove the following statement:

**There exists a vector in $E_2$ which can be expressed as a linear combination of vectors in $E_1$.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be linearly independent eigenvectors of the linear transformation $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_1$, and suppose $w$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_2$ that can be written as a linear combination of $v_1,\ldots,v_n$. Then there exist $c_1,\ldots,c_n$, not all 0, such that
$$w = c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_nv_n.$$
Applying $T$ onto both sides yields
$$Tw = c_1Tv_1 + \cdots + c_nTv_n,$$
$$\lambda_2w = c_1\lambda_1v_1 + \cdots + c_n\lambda_1v_n.$$
Multiplying the first equation by $\lambda_2$ yields
$$\lambda_2w = c_1\lambda_2v_1 + \cdots + c_n\lambda_2v_n.$$
Subtracting the last two equations,
$$\mathbf{0} = c_1(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2)v_1 + \cdots + c_n(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2)v_n.$$
By assumption, $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are linearly independent, so the coefficients are zero. Since at least one of the $c_i$ was non-zero, we have $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$, a contradiction.

Comment: The question does not ask for a linear combination of _linearly independent_ eigenvectors.

Comment: If a vector can be written as a linear combination of a set of vectors, it can also be written as a linear combination of the subset of vectors that are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvectors for a given eigenvalue always form a subspace*. As subspaces are closed under linear combinations, then your question is identical to the question of whether the subspaces here intersect non-trivially, that is, this is true if and only if there exists some non-zero vector v in both sets.

This will only be true if $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$ (consider A*v for this vector in both spaces)

For proof that the eigenvectors form a subspace, for any vectors u and v

$$A*kv = k *Av = k * \lambda v = \lambda * kv$$

$$A(u+v) = Au + Av = \lambda u + \lambda v = \lambda (u + v)$$

Thus all linear combinations of any eigenvectors for the same eigenvalue are also eigenvectors for that value, i.e. these eigenvectors are a subspace

Comment: Subspaces always intersect. You should mention the zero vector somewhere.