# Distinct eigenvalues and matrices problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a real vector space and $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation. 
It is given that  if $v_1, . . . , v_n$ are eigenvectors
for distinct eigenvalues $λ_1, . . . λ_n$ then $\{v_1, . . . , v_n\}$ is linearly independent.

Now let $\{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ be a basis of eigenvectors with distinct eigenvalues
$λ_1, . . . , λ_n$. Prove that for any linear map $S : V → V$ with $ST = TS$, $v_i$ is also an eigenvector of $S$ for each $i = 1, . . . , n$

I have been going round in circles with this for ages.

$T(v)=\lambda v$

$\iff STv=\lambda Sv$

$\iff T(Sv)=\lambda Sv$

There is more pointless algebra but I can't get further than than the previous line where you can deduce $Sv$ is also an eigenvector for $T$
I havent used the fact the question gave at the start which I suspect is what's missing: "if $v_1, . . . , v_n$ are eigenvectors
for distinct eigenvalues $λ_1, . . . λ_n$ then $\{v_1, . . . , v_n\}$ is linearly independent."

I am struggling to find a way to use this however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$Sv_i$ is an eigenvector for $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. The dimension of each eigenspace of $T$ is 1 since the eigenvalues are distinct, so $Sv_i = c_iv_i$ for some $c_i$.

Comment: Could you explain why the dimension of each eigenspace is 1 because theyre distinct? And why the result after follows?

Comment: See if this link answer's your question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408752/given-two-set-of-eigenvectors-can-one-be-represented-by-another/1408769#1408769

Comment: I've read it and understand it- but I'm afraid I still cannot see why the eigenspace must have dimension $1$. Your answer also suggests the basis of each eigenspace is $v_i$. Why?

Comment: Because each eigenvalue corresponds to one of the $v_i$ and only one (from the link).

Comment: I have just realised I can use the fact that the geometric multiplicity $\leq$  algebraic multiplicity- each eigenspace by definition by definition of what an eigenvalue is must consist of more than the $0$ vector so the dimension is $>0$. So $dim E_i =1$ . I will think about your way a bit more also however.

Comment: The geometric multiplicity and algebraic multiplicity was what I had first typed out but I wasn't sure if you were familiar with those terms. This is a much better way of thinking about it too

Comment: But in your proof $v_1, v_2,...,v_n$ correspond to $\lambda_i$?? Also all I can gauge from that proof is the intersection of all the eigenspaces is only the $0$ vector

Comment: Oh, no you're misreading the question in the link. The $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ in that question is different from the $v_i$ in this post. But it appears you got what I wanted out of the link: the intersections of eigenspaces is only the 0 vector.

Comment: So if the eigenspace for $\lambda_1$ had a basis of size $2$ say and all the rest had dimensions $1$. Why would this lead to a problem?

Comment: Well if $\lambda_1$ had multiplicity 2 or more this is no problem. It would just imply there are $n-1$ or less eigenvalues (fundamental theorem of algebra). If it had multiplicity 1 then there would be $n+1$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ and that's not possible.

Answer (score 4):

You have stated that $\{ v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$ with distinct eigenvalues
$\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n\}$. And you have assumed that $S$ is another linear operator on $V$ that commutes with $T$.

Because $TS=ST$, then
$$
           TSv_j = STv_j = \lambda_j Sv_j.
$$
Because $\{ v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n \}$ is a basis, then
$$
     Sv_j = \alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 + \cdots + \alpha_n v_n, \\
     Sv_j - \alpha_j v_j = \sum_{k=1,k\ne j}^{n}\alpha_k v_k
$$
The left side is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_j$. Therefore,
$$
            0 = (T-\lambda_j I)(Sv_j-\alpha_j v_j) = \sum_{k=1,k\ne j}^{n}\alpha_k(\lambda_k-\lambda_j)v_k.
$$
Because the vectors on the right are linearly independent and $\lambda_j \ne \lambda_k$ for $j \ne k$, then $\alpha_k = 0$ for all $k$ such that $k \ne j$. Therefore
$$
                Sv_j - \alpha_j v_j = 0 \implies Sv_j = \alpha_j v_j.
$$
This proves that $v_j$ is an eigenvector of $S$ for all $1 \le j \le n$.

Comment: Fantastic solution! thank you- the one before was just a little more concise- and well presented also- but I really love yours too. I gave positive rating